# Usage and grammar rules for the verb "remain"

Tags: grammar, usage

i have google the usage with different combination of tenses for the verb remain such as

- is/are remained
- will be remained

it seems like it's wrong in grammar to use past participle and future forms. Many website has stated the usage is error in term of grammar.

but i can't get the sense of the grammatical error, can anyone advice me?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use past participle and future forms for "to remain".

Past participle: "has remained" e.g. "He has remained on the island to guard the treasure."

Future: "will remain" "You will remain silent until you are asked to speak."

The two forms you mention are passive-voice constructions that would be used for transitive verbs (like "see", "bite", "hear", "love", etc. that can be done on an object.) Examples: "He is loved."; "We are seen."; "They will be heard"; "You will be bitten."

Intransitive verbs (like "go", "sneeze", "sit", etc., that can't be performed on a direct object) don't have those passive forms. We don't say, "He is sneezed."; "We are died."; "She will be sat." Same with "remain."

Answer (score 0):

The participle "remained" is not normally used -- something cannot be *remained*.

You may be confusing it with the simple past, or the perfect form of the verb:

> They **remained** at home while their father went to the store.
>
> Elizabeth II **has remained** queen longer than any other English monarch.